# Limiting swagger docs visibility

Tags: swagger

after i run my api service, my swagger docs is at localhost:port/docs.
This will show all of my apis. Is there anyway to show only certain api or api under certain tag?

Perhaps a different docs url for all api under certain tag?

I'm running it with express.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like you have a single OpenAPI specification for all your APIs. If you want separation between APIs, you should generate your doc such that each API has its own documentation.

There seems to be discussion on having the ability to show/hide API but it has not been implemented yet: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/433